# Testing self.assertEqual one or another

Tags: python, testing

In Python tests I know how to check the expected value of a variable:

```
def test_smth(self):
    var = 4
    self.assertEqual(var, 4)
```

But is it possible to check with one or another variable without flooding the code with `if`?

Something like:

```
def test_smth(self):
    var = 5
    self.assertEqual(var, 4 or 5)  # this doesn't work
```

Comment: `self.assertIn(var, (4, 5))`? The docs have [a list of the assert methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods). And `4 or 5` just evaluates to `4`, as I guess you've found out.

Comment: Thanks! Missed that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).

```
self.assertIn(var, (4, 5))
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) is link to docs.